# php: converting an array in string

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, warnings

I was trying to make a function con convert an array in a string value, the code is:

```
function makestring($array)
  {
  $outval = '';
  foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
    if(is_array($value))
      {
      $outval .= makestring($value);
      }
    else
      {
      $outval .= $value;
      }
    }
  return $outval;
  }
```

But I get this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Check your array is not empty

Comment: Check the typeof `$array` is really an `Array` or not and not an empty

Answer (score 1):

```
function makestring($array)
{
    if(is_array( $array )) {
        $outval = '';
        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                $outval .= makestring($value);
            }
            else
            {
                $outval .= $value;
            }
        }
        return $outval;
    } else {
        die("Supplied argument is not an array");
    }
}
OR 
function makestring( array $array)
{
    // you code goes here
}
```

Try this. You need to check passing argument is `array` or not before you use `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an error in foreach, it's better to set type to variable:

```
foreach((array)$someArray as $data) {
```

Even if $someArray is not an array, you'll not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

**→ Try this:**

```
  function makestring($array)
  {
       $outval = '';
       $keys = array_keys( $array );

       for( $x = 0; $x < count( $array ); $x++ )
       {
            if( is_array( $array[ $keys[ $x ] ] ) )
            {
                 $outval .= makestring( $array[ $keys[ $x ] ] );
            }
            else
            {
                 $outval .= $array[ $keys[ $x ] ];
            }
       }
  return $outval;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the variables you use $key and $value has old data in them , normally a unset($key,$value) in the end of a foreach will cure that

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    array(
        '4',
        '5',
        array(
            '6',
            '7'
        )
    )
);
$output = null;
if(!is_array($array)){
    $array = array($array);
}
// use a reference to the $output in the callback
array_walk_recursive($array, function($array_element) use (&$output){
    if(is_object($array_element) and method_exists($array_element, '__toString')){
        $array_element = strval($array_element);
    }
    if(is_scalar($array_element)){
        $output .= $array_element;
    }else{
        // found a non scalar... handle it! :)
    }
});
echo $output;
```

Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk_recursive((array) $array, function($val, $key) {
  global $result;
  $result .= $val;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive implode() this convert multidimensional array to string

```
function mYimplode($array, $delimeter) {
 $result='';
 foreach ($array as $key) {
    if (is_array($key)) {
        $result .= mYimplode($key, $delimeter) . $delimeter;
    } else {
        $result .= $key . $delimeter;
    }
 }

 $result = substr($result, 0, 0-strlen($delimeter));

 return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You check via

```
if(is_array($value))
{
  $outval .= makestring($value);
}
```

whether to call `makestring()` recursively. However, in the code that enters `makestring()` in the first place, you do no such check. That's ok, but then you have to check in `makestring()`, whether you actually got an array from the caller. That's called defensive programming.

Another option is to do the check on the calling side. That's part of Design By Contract™:

```
$var = i_usually_give_you_an_array_but_i_might_also_fail();
if (is_array($var)) {
  echo makestring($value);
}
```